# Codeigniter SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, no such table: db_users

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I have just downloaded an auth system for codeigniter4
But when I go to `/register` I get this error

```
`SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, no such table: db_users`
```

Please note:

- I have a table called `users` I do not want to use SQLite at all but MySql
- I have configured the default driver to be `MySQL` in my `.env` file and inputted my database details
- I have no idea why codigniter is trying to execute a SQLite query

Please help

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I did not properly set up the db config.

I was on the development server so I had to configure`$tests`(App/Confif/Database.php) to my correct Db details

Answer (score 0):

pleas provide what you tried and where you doing it. are you working on model or directly writing queries in controller.

you can execute queries using model as it has inbuilt database library function for ex.:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table_name');
$this->db->get()->row();
```

Comment: 0

on which line you get the error. can you put the part of the code. and are you working on live server or localhost. this will help me to set up your db config properly.